# Why do I need two ends here

Tags: ruby, loops

Just learning a bit of Ruby.
This code works OK but so far as I understand, the "end" at the end is superfluous. Can someone help me match my ends up?

```
def sum arr
  # YOUR CODE HERE
  total = 0
  if !arr.empty?
    arr.each do |element|
    total += element
  end
  return total
end
end

puts sum([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: Thank you. The incorrect indenting is a symptom of my problem, not the cause. -1 ing for that reason is a bit off. IMHO The precise issue was that I did not see the lack of an end in the each-do bit.

Comment: @nerak99 it is the cause of the question I have updated your indenting and now it should be clear why you need 2 ends

Comment: @engineersmnky: should've been an answer. With your edit the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Approved helpful edit. @engineersmnky thanks. "at"SergioTulentsev the question may have been idiomatic English but it did make sense to the people who answered helpfully.
 You might consider that it is not compulsory to answer, if you just want to criticise, try and make the criticism constructive.

Comment: I've restored the original question to show the OP's actual problem.

Comment: All of this discussion about syntax prompts me to assist overall at this point. @nerak99 while your solution now works might I recommend taking a look at [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce). This method will allow you to simplify your body code to `arr.reduce(:+) || 0`. This will return the sum of the digits or if arr is empty it will return 0. (caveat due to duck typing if the elements of arr are not all Numeric or all of the same data type this may cause differing results)

Comment: @engineersmnky you can also pass the initial value: `arr.reduce(0, :+)`

Comment: It is interesting that this question 'earned' -2 credits. I am on forums such as this regularly and very rarely does this happen. IMHO the person who awarded the points decided the question was trivial. In the end it was. Many years ago, in the days of ver crude editors I spent hours trying to fix a program and had spelled 'else' as 'esle'. This was equally a trivial point but real nevertheless.
Down-voting should be kept for Qs that waste time to the point of abuse (which is what I reserve it for) rather than trying to scare away people with problems that they might be nervous of sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sum arr
  # YOUR CODE HERE
  total = 0
  if !arr.empty?
    arr.each do |element|
      total += element
    end
    return total
  end
end
```

it is not superfluous. You put `end` identifier also when defining a block.

Comment: Thanks, Much more helpful than my previous assistant. (I really think you should need a license in good manners before you are allowed to -1 things.)

Answer (score 2):

Proper indention of your code will usually help you discover these sorts of issues easier, but I've added comments where certain statements require an 'end' so you can see what's happening in your code.

```
def sum arr       # A def will match up with up one 'end'
  total = 0  
  if !arr.empty?  # A if  will match up with up one 'end'
    arr.each do |element|  # A do will match up with one 'end'
      total += element
    end                    # Here's the do's end
  return total
  end               # Here's the if's end
end               # Here's the def's end

puts sum([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh I know. :) I was typing as furiously fast as I could.

Comment: Thanks, see my comment above for where I went wrong. Sometimes you can't see for looking.